# After running python database.py command, I am getting some error as in description

Tags: python, database, flask, installation

I have downloaded my friend's repo for some modifications. The technology we are using is flask and using sqllite. While creating database tables using python database.py, I got error saying

```
D:\TYSEM2\Project\Pothole-Prediction-Web-Application-master\Pothole-Prediction-Web-Application-master>python database.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "database.py", line 16, in <module>
    db.execute('ALTER TABLE PTHOLES MODIFY PHONE NUMBER')
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "MODIFY": syntax error
```

Comment: Please check the syntax of your sql command.

Answer (score 0):

`MODIFY` isn't an SQLite keyword, check the list of keywords in the [SQLite Keywords](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) official documentation. Instead, you may like to use `UPDATE` or `ALTER`. Otherwise, check with the author about the query he used as generally `MODIFY` is a keyword for querying into Oracle and MySQL databases.

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to StackOverflow,

First of all, the syntax of your SQL operation isn't good.

For that statement, it's have to be :

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name
MODIFY COLUMN column_name datatype;
```

You miss the datatype here.

But even if you do that, you will have another problem because SQLite3 doesn't allow ALTER operations by default.

I read you used flask for this project. I advise you to have a look at [Flask-SQLAlchemy](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/). It's very handy to manages databases declaration and operations.